# In Excel, How to transform data in row seperated by commas to column with value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have information in excel organised like this.

| name | type | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Thomas | table,height | red,180 |
| Jail | cross,dog | young,cow |

How do I convert it to this?

| name | table | height | cross | dog |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| thomas | red | 180 |  |  |
| Jail |  |  | young | cow |

No idea how to approach this, tried using macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel-2007 - macro only (because SPLIT(any, ",") not present in native functions)

For Excel-2010 install add-in PowerQuery, click dozen times and get result - a script M-language like this:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"ChangeType" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"name", type text}, {"type", type text}, {"data", type text}}),
    #"NewTable" = Table.AddColumn(#"ChangeType", "TypeTable", each Table.FromColumns({Text.SplitAny([type], ","), Text.SplitAny([data], ",")}, {"Type1", "Data1"}) ),
    #"ExpandTable" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"NewTable", "TypeTable", {"Type1", "Data1"}, {"Type1", "Data1"}),
    #"RemoveCSV" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"ExpandTable",{"type", "data"}),
    #"GetResult" = Table.Pivot(#"RemoveCSV", List.Distinct(#"RemoveCSV"[Type1]), "Type1", "Data1")
in
    #"GetResult"
```

[image: SampleResult]

A macro that will make the same job much longer:

```
Function expandTable(aSourceRange As Range) As Variant
Dim aSource As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim aTypes As Variant, aDatas As Variant
Dim aResult() As String
Dim allTypes As New Collection
Rem Extract cell values from source range:
    aSource = aSourceRange.Value2
Rem First collect all unique types:
    For i = LBound(aSource, 1) + 1 To UBound(aSource, 1)
        aTypes = Split(aSource(i, 2), ",")
        For j = LBound(aTypes) To UBound(aTypes)
            Call allTypes.Add(aTypes(j), aTypes(j))
        Next j
    Next i
    i = allTypes.Count + 1
Rem Result table will be same height, but width will be name + all types
    ReDim aResult(LBound(aSource, 1) To UBound(aSource, 1), 1 To i)
Rem Fill first row - header:
    aResult(1, 1) = aSource(1, 1)
    For i = 1 To allTypes.Count
        aResult(LBound(aSource, 1), i + 1) = allTypes.Item(i)
    Next i
Rem Transfer data from source array to result array:
    For i = LBound(aSource, 1) + 1 To UBound(aSource, 1)
        aResult(i, 1) = aSource(i, 1)
        aTypes = Split(aSource(i, 2), ",")
        aDatas = Split(aSource(i, 3), ",")
Rem Equalize the sizes of arrays of Types and Data -
Rem if they have a different number of elements, an error may occur.
        ReDim Preserve aDatas(LBound(aTypes) To UBound(aTypes))
        For j = LBound(aTypes) To UBound(aTypes)
            For k = 2 To UBound(aResult, 2)
                If aResult(1, k) = aTypes(j) Then
                    aResult(i, k) = aDatas(j)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
    expandTable = aResult
End Function
```

*As you can see, using modern, updated tools can save a lot of time and effort. Therefore, just install [**PowerQuery**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379) and learn how to convert data with it - there are many videos on YouTube that show how to convert data from one form to another (it's easy and fun)*